# Google Sheets Formula: List Column A input if Column G input is equal to "X"

Tags: google-sheets

I am interested in finding a formula that will allow me to make lists of cell input from Column A, but only list the cells that have a certain value in the same row in Column G.

Here's more information:  I am doing rosters for my school.  Each row is a different student, their name entered into Column A.  Columns G through J are their assigned classes on certain days.  I would like to pull lists of students who have certain classes on specific days (Tuesday through Friday).  For instance,  I would like a formula that allows me to make a list of all students (Name from Column A) whose class listed in column G is "Art."  So basically I want to pull daily class rosters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated by me and all of my teacher colleagues!

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of formula, You could simply try FILTER VIEWS. Select your table and click create a filter. Google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 =FILTER (A1:J200,G1:G200="Art")
```

Or

```
= FILTER ({A1:A200,G1:G200},G1:G200="Art")
```

You're looking for this function [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)

You could also use [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

```
 =QUERY (A1:J200,"Select A,B,C,D,F,G,J Where G contains 'Art'")
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, Mark this as solved by clicking `✔` on the left.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  You are my hero!!